# MenuItems' Icon size changes on different systems

Tags: wpf, xaml, icons, menuitem

I have a WPF `UserControl` hosted inside of a WinForms application. This `UserControl` has a `ContentControl` which has a `ContextMenu`. The `ContextMenu` has a few `MenuItem`s, all of which have their `Icon` property set to a `.ico`.

For whatever reason, the icons become massive on different systems. I've tested them on a Windows 10 and Windows 7 machine and they are fine, but other win10/win7 machines they are huge.

The actual `.ico` files range from 32x32 bit to 256x256.

Here's how they look normally:
[image]

Here's how they look on certain machines:
[image]

Here's the .xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestUC.MainWindow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" Height="737.239" Width="1455.446"
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl>
            <ContentControl.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Pan">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="Images/panHand.ico" />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="Zoom In">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="Images/zoom_In.ico" />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="Zoom Out">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="Images/zoom_Out.ico" />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </ContentControl.ContextMenu>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I can go ahead and manually set the `Height` and `Width`, but I would love to know what causes this.

Comment: In WPF, based on resolution and Scaling, the image size will be vary. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hidpi/declaring-managed-apps-dpi-aware

Answer (score 1):

It's my understanding the user setting for icon size will influence this particular scenario.

They pick big icons then windows will prefer the big version of the ico.

I'm not sure about that because I never risk default sizes for Image.

In any event, it's picking 256x256 and you gave it no size so it decides that image is 256x256.

IMO.

It's a bad idea to use ico or any bitmap file for this stuff in a wpf app.

You're best using vector graphics.

A Path for simple iconography.

With a menu, that does also mean some re-templating or replacing the header.

But you can then have consistent scaleable iconography across your application.

Using very lightweight geometries in a resource dictionary.